# Why does my usage of the unstable naked assembly feature segfault on a movaps instruction?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64

I know my code have used lots of unsafe and inline assembly, but I still want to know why it segfault only on release mode. I tried lower opt-level but it can only run when opt-level is 1.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=e13c63ce860f8d7796e57182fb5f14b0):

```
//! green-threads is a toy implementation on user-space threads in non-preemptive multitasking.
//! This implementation is mostly guided by cfsamson's tutorial:
//! https://cfsamson.gitbook.io/green-threads-explained-in-200-lines-of-rust/green-threads.
#![deny(missing_docs)]
#![feature(llvm_asm)]
#![feature(naked_functions)]

use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::ptr;

const DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE: usize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
static mut RUNTIME: usize = 0;

/// Runtime schedule and switch threads. current is the id of thread which is currently running.
pub struct Runtime {
    queue: VecDeque<Task>,
    current: Task,
}

/// ThreadContext contains the registers marked as "callee-saved" (preserved across calls)
/// in the specification of x86-64 architecture. They contain all the information
/// we need to resume a thread.
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
#[repr(C)]
struct ThreadContext {
    rsp: u64,
    r15: u64,
    r14: u64,
    r13: u64,
    r12: u64,
    rbx: u64,
    rbp: u64,
}

struct Task {
    stack: Vec<u8>,
    ctx: ThreadContext,
}

impl Task {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Task {
            stack: vec![0_u8; DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE],
            ctx: ThreadContext::default(),
        }
    }
}

impl Runtime {
    /// Initialize with a base thread.
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let base_thread = Task::new();

        Runtime {
            queue: VecDeque::new(),
            current: base_thread,
        }
    }

    /// This is cheating a bit, but we need a pointer to our Runtime
    /// stored so we can call yield on it even if we don't have a
    /// reference to it.
    pub fn init(&self) {
        unsafe {
            let r_ptr: *const Runtime = self;
            RUNTIME = r_ptr as usize;
        }
    }

    /// start the runtime
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        while self.t_yield() {}
    }

    fn t_return(&mut self) -> bool {
        if self.queue.len() == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        let mut next = self.queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        std::mem::swap(&mut next, &mut self.current);

        unsafe {
            switch(&mut next.ctx, &self.current.ctx);
        }

        self.queue.len() > 0
    }

    fn t_yield(&mut self) -> bool {
        if self.queue.len() == 0 {
            return false;
        }

        let mut next = self.queue.pop_front().unwrap();
        std::mem::swap(&mut next, &mut self.current);
        self.queue.push_back(next);

        unsafe {
            let last = self.queue.len() - 1;
            switch(&mut self.queue[last].ctx, &self.current.ctx);
        }
        // Prevents compiler from optimizing our code away on Windows.
        self.queue.len() > 0
    }

    /// spawn a function to be executed by runtime
    pub fn spawn(&mut self, f: fn()) {
        let mut available = Task::new();

        let size = available.stack.len();
        let s_ptr = available.stack.as_mut_ptr();

        unsafe {
            // put the f to the 16 bytes aligned position.
            ptr::write(s_ptr.offset((size - 32) as isize) as *mut u64, f as u64);
            // put the guard 1 byte next to the f for being executed after f returned.
            ptr::write(s_ptr.offset((size - 24) as isize) as *mut u64, guard as u64);

            available.ctx.rsp = s_ptr.offset((size - 32) as isize) as u64;
        }

        self.queue.push_back(available);
    }
}

fn guard() {
    unsafe {
        let rt_ptr = RUNTIME as *mut Runtime;
        (*rt_ptr).t_return();
    }
}

/// yield_thread is a helper function that lets us call yield from an arbitrary place in our code.
pub fn yield_thread() {
    unsafe {
        let rt_ptr = RUNTIME as *mut Runtime;
        (*rt_ptr).t_yield();
    };
}

#[naked]
#[inline(never)]
unsafe fn switch(old: *mut ThreadContext, new: *const ThreadContext) {
    llvm_asm!("
        mov     %rsp, 0x00($0)
        mov     %r15, 0x08($0)
        mov     %r14, 0x10($0)
        mov     %r13, 0x18($0)
        mov     %r12, 0x20($0)
        mov     %rbx, 0x28($0)
        mov     %rbp, 0x30($0)
        mov     0x00($1), %rsp
        mov     0x08($1), %r15
        mov     0x10($1), %r14
        mov     0x18($1), %r13
        mov     0x20($1), %r12
        mov     0x28($1), %rbx
        mov     0x30($1), %rbp
        ret
        "
    :
    :"r"(old), "r"(new)
    :
    : "volatile", "alignstack"
    );
}

fn main() {
    let mut runtime = Runtime::new();
    runtime.init();
    runtime.spawn(|| {});
    runtime.run();
}
```

the exact segfault point is at

```
    mov qword ptr [rsp + 144], rdi
    movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx + rsi + 56]
; Here
    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp + 128], xmm0
    movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdx + rsi + 40]
    movaps  xmmword ptr [rsp + 112], xmm0
```

which is inlined `pop_front` in inlined `t_return`

update2: after the first answer  and some more test, the problem is `movaps` requires `[rsp + 128]` to be 16 byte aligned, but `rsp` is not. The entry of `guard`(which inlined `t_return`) is following

more detail in my own answer

Comment: Did you try your code in a debugger and checked where the segmentation fault occured?

Comment: Are you sure about the usage of `#[naked]`? I can't find whether the caller sets the arguments or not correctly.

Comment: @zela yes, I wrongly publish this question when still editing

Comment: Whether `[rsp+128]` is `0x0` or not doesn't really matter it would get loaded without fault. The fault is likely because `rsp` got misaligned.

Comment: Did you compare the generated assembly from *not* in release mode to the assembly *in* release mode?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the 152 because stack is misaligned by 8 on entry due to the return address.

Comment: @Jester it's not, I stand corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segfault on `movaps` to/from the stack is often a sign that you violated the ABI and mis-aligned the stack pointer.  Probably debug mode doesn't auto-vectorize the copy of whatever is being copied here.

`movaps` requires 16-byte alignment for its memory operand, unlike `movups`.  The compiler uses `movaps` because it's more efficient on older CPUs.  The ABI guarantees 16-byte stack alignment on entry to any function, so it can get 16-byte alignment for locals for free.  (ABI guarantees like this are things that compilers are supposed to assume without checking, for efficiency.)

Note that this is copying 32 bytes *from* `[rdx+rsi+40]` *to* stack memory, so the contents of that stack memory before the store executes are irrelevant.

Comment: Is my interpretation is right that this segfault lies in stack isn't 16 byte aligned so `movaps` fails?

Comment: @Austaras: That's my guess, yes.  If RSP is 16-byte aligned, RSP+128 will be as well.  You can check the value of the RSP register with your debugger.  (The low hex digit of its value should be `0`.)

Answer (score 2):

After more testing and the [great help of Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63015581/155423) it turns out that the original [implementation in the tutorial](https://cfsamson.gitbook.io/green-threads-explained-in-200-lines-of-rust/final-200-lines-of-code) is flawed and so is mine. The problem lies in using the next 8 bytes to store a function pointer to `guard`.

When the spawned function returns, it pops the top of the stack to `%rip`, and thus runs `guard`. Unlike a normal function call, where the caller takes care of stack alignment, this will cause the stack in `guard` to no longer be aligned to 16 bytes. When subsequently using `movaps`, this program segfaults.